# android-ScrollView Issue

Tags: android, scrollview

When the items that I used started to fill whole screen I decided to use scrollview,but when I use it,ScrollView compressing the layouts of items and put them in a smaller part of screen as the following:

[image]

And here is my xml.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#A4A4A4">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home_ico"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/internet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:text="@string/internet"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/servisler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:text="@string/servisler"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kampanya"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:text="@string/kampanya"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hakkımızda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:text="@string/hakkımızda"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Diğer" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            />
        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:centered="true"
            app:fillColor="#ff0099"
            app:pageColor="#FF0000"
            app:snap="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/textView4"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/textView5"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/textView6"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/textView7"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/textView8"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/textView9"/>
    </LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#FF0000FF" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="wefwfw"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:drawable="@drawable/adsl"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="qwgq"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="qwgq"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FF0000FF" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="wefwfw"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:drawable="@drawable/adsl"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="qwgq"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="qwgq"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF0000FF" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="wefwfw"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:drawable="@drawable/adsl"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="qwgq"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="qwgq"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FF0000FF" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="wefwfw"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:drawable="@drawable/adsl"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="qwgq"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="qwgq"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF0000FF" />
</LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

So what is my problem? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try changing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on immediate child of `ScrollView` which is `LinearLayout`

Comment: I tried but no luck.

Comment: Why you user layout_weight?

Comment: To divide the screeen how I want it